# How to eliminate index error in python at the time of defining function

Tags: python

How to eliminate error like:

```
('sel.ST80__Active_power_control_on_B2==0', 'occurred at index 2017-12-01 00:00:00')
```

`ST80` is a controller signal

While calling function,the above error is coming.

```
batt_status=0.

def func(x):
    global batt_status
    global f
    global f1
    global f2

    if ((x['avail_for_batt']>0.) & (x['f'])):
         batt_status +=(x['avail_for_batt']/3600.)
    elif ((x['avail_for_batt']>0.) & x['f1']):
        batt_status +=(x['avail_for_batt']/3600.)
    elif ((x['avail_for_batt']>0.)& (x['f2'])):
        batt_status +=(x['avail_for_batt']/3600.)
    else:
         pass

sel['charg']=sel.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: Try looking at your question as someone who doesn't know your code nor what it is doing. There is not enough context to give a sensible answer. If there is an exception, then please add the *complete* traceback to the question.